# Multi-thread syncronizing using Visual c++ do not work

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I'm studying multi-thread program using Visual c++ to develop a sound signal processing program. To create basic structure of the program, I wrote a simple code having four threads that move synchronously, but they do not work well.
Specifications are as follows.

1. There are four threads: bg_thread, main_thread, sub_thread [0], sub_thread [1].
2. bg_thread triggers main_thread at regular intervals
3. main_thread triggers sub_thread [0] every time and triggers sub_thread [1] once every two times.
4. main_thread is a function in main_class
5. sub_thread [0], sub_thread [1] are functions in sub_class

The program is as follows:

---

```
#include "process.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

class Sub_class
{
public:
    HANDLE hEvent2;
    Sub_class(int no);
    bool loop_ok;
    bool calcstart;
    int sub_class_no;

    void do_sub_loop2();
};

class Main_class {
public:
    bool thread_go;
    bool go_flag = false;
    Sub_class *sub_cls[2];

    Main_class();
    ~Main_class();
    int start_loop();
};

Main_class *main_cls = 0;
HANDLE g_bg_wait = 0;
HANDLE g_main_event = 0;
bool bg_go = true;

unsigned __stdcall start_bg_loop(void *parg)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(g_bg_wait, INFINITE);

    while (bg_go)
    {
        Sleep(100); // goto sleep for 100 milliseconds
        SetEvent(g_main_event);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall start_main_loop(void *parg)
{
    main_cls->start_loop();
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    main_cls = new Main_class();

    HANDLE hEvent = 0;
    HANDLE hndl = 0;

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "bg_event");
    hndl = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &start_bg_loop, 0, 0, 0);
    g_bg_wait = hEvent;

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "main_event");
    hndl = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &start_main_loop, 0, 0, 0);
    g_main_event = hEvent;

    main_cls->sub_cls[0] = new Sub_class(0);
    main_cls->sub_cls[1] = new Sub_class(1);

    Sleep(1000);

    bg_go = false;
    CloseHandle(g_bg_wait);
    CloseHandle(g_main_event);
}


int Main_class::start_loop()
{
    Sleep(10);
    SetEvent(g_bg_wait);

    while (thread_go)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(g_main_event, INFINITE);

        printf("Trigger SubClass 0\n");
        sub_cls[0]->calcstart = true;
        SetEvent(sub_cls[0]->hEvent2);

        if (go_flag)
        {
            printf("Trigger SubClass 1\n");
            sub_cls[1]->calcstart = true;
            SetEvent(sub_cls[1]->hEvent2);
        }
        else
        {
            sub_cls[1]->calcstart = false;
        }
        go_flag = !go_flag;
    }
    return 0;
}

Main_class::Main_class()
{
    thread_go = true;
}

Main_class::~Main_class()
{
    thread_go = false;
}

static unsigned __stdcall executeLauncher2(void* args) {
    reinterpret_cast<Sub_class*>(args)->do_sub_loop2();
    return 0;
}
Sub_class::Sub_class(int no)
{
    sub_class_no = no;
    loop_ok = true;
    hEvent2 = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, "event_2");
    _beginthreadex(0, 0, &executeLauncher2, (void *)this, 0, 0);
}
void Sub_class::do_sub_loop2()
{
    while (loop_ok)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hEvent2, INFINITE);
        if (calcstart) printf("Start SubClass %d : OK\n", sub_class_no);
        else printf("Start SubClass %d : NG ---\n", sub_class_no);
    }
}
```

The result of running this program is as follows:

---

```
Trigger SubClass 0
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Trigger SubClass 1
Start SubClass 1 : NG ---
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Start SubClass 1 : NG ---
Trigger SubClass 0
Trigger SubClass 1
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Start SubClass 1 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Trigger SubClass 1
Start SubClass 1 : NG ---
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Start SubClass 1 : NG ---
Trigger SubClass 0
Trigger SubClass 1
Start SubClass 1 : OK
Start SubClass 0 : OK
Trigger SubClass 0
Start SubClass 1 : NG ---
```

As you can see from the result, sub_thread [1] is often invoked (line of NG) even though triggering sub_thread [0].
I want to create the program so that when sub_thread [0] is triggered, sub_thread [0] is invoked and when sub_thread [1] is triggered, 
sub_thread [1] is invoked, that is, I want to prevent NG lines.

Could you teach me how to fix this program, please ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If they are both waiting on the same event you can't control which one responds when the event is triggered.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: In this program, different events are created in the class initializations and waiting for each SetEvent. But, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> `CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, "event_2");`

Here you create or open the *same* event, because you pass a name to the function. Even multiple instances of your program would open the same event object. If any other program had created an event with such a generic name as "event_2", you would also open that. That's certainly not what you want.

Pass `NULL` for the last parameter to create distinct event objects for each thread. Named events are usually only used for cross-process synchronization (in which case one uses unique names like a GUID), which you don't need here.

Comment: Great!!! The problem is solved. My understanding about CreateEvent was so immature. Thank you very much.

Comment: @S.Ise You propably already know now, that you should also change the other calls to `CreateEvent` to pass `NULL` for the last parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Well, I found the last parameter should be null unless I use OpenEvent.